# Bad Exception Handling? Program keeps looping?

Tags: java

So I'm currently dealing with this [keep in mind I cut most of the code out cause it's quite long]

```
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 7){ 

    System.out.println("---  Mathematical Calculator  ---");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Pick an operation from the list - Use nos. 1 to 7");
    System.out.println("1) Multiplication");
    System.out.println("2) Division");
    System.out.println("3) Addition");
    System.out.println("4) Subtraction");
    System.out.println("5) Find the area of a regular object");
    System.out.println("6) Find the volume of a regular object");
    System.out.println("7) Exit Program");  

    **boolean ok = false;
    do {
        try{
            choice = userInput.nextInt();
            ok = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                    }
    }
    while (ok = false);**

    switch (choice) {

    case 1:

    case 2: 

    case 3:

    case 4:

    case 5:

    case 6:



 case 7:            
System.out.println("Thanks for using my program"); 
            System.out.println("Program terminated");
            break; 





    default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");

        }

    }
    userInput.close();
}
```

So currently, when I run the program and enter something that is NOT an integer, the program will give the following output:

```
---  Mathematical Calculator  ---

Pick an operation from the list - Use nos. 1 to 7
1) Multiplication
2) Division
3) Addition
4) Subtraction
5) Find the area of a regular object
6) Find the volume of a regular object
7) Exit Program
Invalid input
Invalid choice

Over
And over
And over
```

I know I've probably done something wrong with the exception handling (program works fine with valid input), but I really don't know how I can fix it.

Help?

Comment: what are the double asterisks? a copy-paste problem? or an attempt to boldface the block?

Answer (score 3):

You need to catch the \n\r with an `userInput.nextLine()` in your exception and it stops printing for ever like this

```
catch (InputMismatchException e){
       System.out.println("Invalid input");
       userInput.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Worked.  I had tried putting a nextInt(); which didn't work, thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 2):

`while (ok = false);` should be `while (ok == false);`, or `while (!ok);`.

`ok = false` is an assignment.

Also, I guess you have intentionally left the cases empty, but even so, make sure that you put a `break;` on each of them, otherwise the option 7 will always be executed.

EDIT: for the infinite loop, you should also do what Kevin Esche suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31961614/2516301) (+1).

Comment: Yes both of you were right...as for the cases, yes I did put a break.